# Word Add-In, C# VSTO, Ribbon XML, what's the signature for the built-in "undo" command's handler?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto

I figure this is a long shot, but I'm a bit desperate and Microsoft is no help. I'm creating an add-in that needs to support undoing. Some add-in operations modify the document, but also perform actions *outside* the document. The **former** end-up in Word's undo stack and I can even group them as a custom undo record to make them atomic, but I need to also be able to undo the **latter** when that undo record is, well, "undone" by Word.

Initially, I had hoped there would be some "beforeUndo" and "afterUndo" events I could handle, but I can't find any. Googling in every direction, I stumbled across the possibility of "repurposing" Word's commands in my Ribbon XML to handle them myself. The example I found was for the "Save" command, and it goes like this:

`<button idMso="FileSave" onAction="MySave"/>`

This requires a handler with this signature:

`public void MySave (Office.IRibbonControl control, bool cancel)`

This works as you'd expect. So I looked up the idMso for "Undo", and found that it's not a "button", but a "gallery", and so wrote this in my Ribbon XML:

`<gallery idMso="Undo" onAction="MyUndo" />`

And I gave MyUndo the same signature as MySave.

Word's "undo" control does correctly show-up in my add-in's ribbon tab, HOWEVER "MyUndo" doesn't get called. My educated guess is that "MyUndo" should have a different signature.

I couldn't find any information on this through Googling, so here I am. In practice I have two problems to solve:

1. Get my undo handler to get called with the user "undoes" something
2. Get the name of the undo record that was (or is being) undone

I don't even know if I'm using the correct approach to implement the feature I described, so I'm open to any option that lets me add my own code to a custom undo record. I'd be much happier if this could be done through events, though... Ribbon XML makes me feel dirty :-D